# Automatic notifications from Bitbucket

Tags: email, notifications, twitter-integration, bitbucket

I created a repository on the Bitbucket. And in *Admin* tab I found *Services* configuration. As I understand services allow to integrate with email, twitter and so on.

I expected that once I configured a service (email-service, for instance) I would receive email notifications about new changesets (when someone make hg 'push' command). But I don't receive anything.

What's the correct way to configure automatic notifications about new changesets on Bitbucket? And what do the services really do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty easy to set up email notifications you just enter the email address that you want the notifications to be sent to.

Have you checked that

- the email hasn't been marked as spam - emails are sent from `commits-noreply@bitbucket.org`
- you have pushed the changes to the remote server (Bitbucket) and they aren't being pushed to a local repository.
- the email address you have added is correct

Complete information on configuring Bitbucket services [can be found here](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Managing+Bitbucket+Services).  In particular email configuration [can be found here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Email+Service+Management).

Comment: Thanks, Barry. Unfortunally, all these steps I've already done before asking the question.

Comment: @Roman - I would then suggest raising a support ticket with Bitbucket directly. Thanks